# What is the definition of the phrase "ego robot"?

Tags: mobile-robot, cameras, navigation, visual-odometry, multi-agent

What does the phrase "ego robot" mean? I see it used in the context of multi robot systems like in the paper [Game Theoretic Motion Planning for Multi-robot Racing](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-05816-6_16) by Zijian Wang, Riccardo Spica & Mac Schwager, and also in visual odometry.

Comment: The term ego is used for your own robot, the robot that you are creating the path etc.

Comment: When linking it's best to avoid *here* for the link text. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) and if this happens, *here* doesn't help anyone find the page. Often missing pages haven't been removed, they have just been moved to another location. If you give the page or pater title as the link text then a search for that text will often find the new location. Adding Authors or a doi: makes it even easier to find a specific paper.